# Why do these two variables sync up in NASM

Tags: variables, assembly, nasm

I am a beginner in NASM and I have encountered something I can not understand. Given this code:

```
    global  main
    extern  printf

    section .text
main:
    mov  qword  [VAR_0], 1 ; Init first variable
    mov qword [VAR_1], 2   ; Init second variable
    mov    rdi, format     ; Print first variable -> outputs 2
    mov    rsi, [VAR_0]
    mov    eax, 0
    call   printf
    mov    rdi, format     ; Print second variable -> outputs 2
    mov    rsi, [VAR_1]
    mov    eax, 0
    call   printf


section .bss
VAR_0: resq    0
VAR_1: resq    0


section .data
format db "%d", 10, 0
```

Why does the program output

```
2
2
```

Instead of

```
1
2
```

I am compiling it with

```
nasm -felf64 test.s
gcc test.o
```

And simply running it as

```
./a.out
```

I am at the end of my wits with this.

Comment: You want `resq 1` to allocate 1 qword, not `resq 0` which allocates 0, so your two variables overlap.

Comment: @Jester That was it. I thought that it was the default value of the variable. Could you please change this into an answer so that I may show my boundless gratitude?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are misusing the `resq` directive.  The proper use is:

```
 IDENTIFIER:    resq    number_quad_words_to_reserve
```

In your case you have:

```
 VAR0:  resq  0
```

This reserves a total of zero quad words.  Modifying each of these to:

```
 VAR0:   resq  1
 VAR1:   resq  1
```

will correct the behavior that you are observing.